# How can send int and string with ajax to C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I need post two argument to method in `C#`

```
 [HttpPost]
 public bool information([FromBody]int idInfromation,[FromBody] string information)
    {
       .....
       return true;
    }
```

with `ajax`, but my solution doesn´t work. `Newtwork` tab is showing:

> POST http://*-----*/information/SubmitAnswer 500 (Internal Server Error)

I have this:

```
var source = { "idInfromation": 5, "information": "Wau" };

$.ajax({
    url: "/information/",
    type: "POST",
    data: source,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Complete");

    }

});
```

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Your action is throwing an exception. Debug it and find out what that exception is.

Comment: it hits /information/SubmitAnswer instead of your information action.

Comment: No, I just rewrote, sorry. But thank you for your note. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass multiple [FormBody] parameters instead you have to pass parameter as an object.
for example, declare a DTO class

```
// DTO
public class InformationClass{
  public int idInfromation{ get; set; }
  public string Information{ get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
 public bool information(InformationDTO Info)
    {
       .....
       return true;
    }
```

to pass object using Json ajax:

```
// Initialize the object, before adding data to it.
//  { } is declarative shorthand for new Object().
var Information= { };

Information.idInfromation= ParseInt($("txtId").val()); // your desired value
Information.Information= $("#Information").val();

// Create a data transfer object (DTO) with the proper structure.
var DTO = { 'Information' : Information};

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "InformationService.asmx/information", // or your specified url, if you don't want //use service like url: "/information/",
  data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
  dataType: "json"
});
```

Hope this helps,
Thanks.

Comment: I do this, but when I was debuging this solution, so DTO.Information.idInformation was 1, but in controller info.idInformation was 0.
And I don´t understand it...

Comment: check with an alert messagebox in ajax for Information.idInfromation= ParseInt($("txtId").val()); // your desired value
Information.Information= $("#Information").val(); and see what are you getting. give value to both id of integer type and information of string type textfield and check what are you getting with alert.

Comment: Problem was elsewhere, but I find it and I solve it. Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return two values with [FromBody].  Either create a DTO class or receive it as a JObject.

Comment: Now, I try create the DTO object, thank you for your advice. :)